# Define an absolute column as lookup_value

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, I am completely new to VBA besides recording simple macros, so bear over with me.

I am creating a VBA macro to import and sort results from a poll, based on names from the answers.
The import will take place from a Data sheet and will be imported into a Results sheet, for this I am using the XLOOKUP function.
The poll will run every other week and each time, the results sheet will expand with one column showing the newest results.

If I were to use the function directly in the spreadsheet this would work:

```
=XLOOKUP(A3&"*";Data!$D$2:$D$20;Data!$F$2:$F$20;"F";2)
```

where A3&"*" is my lookup_value.

I made it work with the offset function, but since my lookup_value has to be absolute I need another solution which I can not figure out.

```
Sub RES_Farver()
 
Dim Farve_Cell As Range

For Each Farve_Cell In Range("B3:B50")

Farve_Cell.Value = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Farve_Cell.Offset(0, -1) & "*", _
Sheets("Data").Range("D2:D50"), Sheets("Data").Range("F2:F50"), "F", 2)

Next Farve_Cell

End Sub
```

Not that Range("B3:B50") will later be based on user input, so it can be dynamic and change over time, like I described earlier.

What would I have to use instead of Offset?

Thanks!

Comment: `Range("A3") & "*"` perhaps.

Comment: Use the same formula. You can enter the formula in the entire range in one go... `Range("B3:B50").Formula = "=XLOOKUP(A3&""*"",Data!$D$2:$D$20;Data!$F$2:$F$20,""F"",2)"`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout `$D$20;Data` semicolon not comma ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout 
Thanks. 
It Works but..
I want it to paste the lookup result as a value, not a formula.
I have headers in my range which is hard to take into account, without using the formula several times or putting another function into it. 

I just want it to look in the column A in the corresponding row when the macro goes through the range.

Comment: After the formula, add another line `Range("B3:B50").Value=Range("B3:B50").Value`

Comment: I went with this
`Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Cells(Farve_Cell.Row, "A") & "*", _
Sheets("Data").Range("D2:D50"), Sheets("Data").Range("F2:F50"), "F", 2)`
Then it will use the Farve_Cell row in column A.
Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @Siddharth Rout

```
Sub lookup()

Dim vRange As String

    vRange = InputBox("Please enter the range.", "Range:", "B3:B50")
    If vRange = "" Then Exit Sub

    Range(vRange).Formula = "=XLOOKUP(A3&""*"",Data!$D$2:$D$20;Data!$F$2:$F$20,""F"",2)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with this

```
result= _
Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Cells(Farve_Cell.Row, "A") & "*", _ 
Sheets("Data").Range("D2:D50"), Sheets("Data").Range("F2:F50"), "F", 2)
```

Then it will use the row Farve_Cell is at in column A.

I also modified the range to only rows containing values and to the current week as column, where I have stated the weeks of the year in row 11
In total it looks like this (with danish messages)

```
Sub RES_Farver()
   
Dim currentWeek As Integer
currentWeek = DatePart("WW", Date, , vbFirstFullWeek)

Dim weekColumn As Integer
Set weekCell = Range("11:11").Find(currentWeek)

If weekCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Ugenummer ikke fundet"
    Exit Sub
Else
    weekColumn = weekCell.Column
End If

Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Cells(13, weekColumn), Cells(lastRow, weekColumn))

For Each Farve_Cell In rng

Dim result As String

result = _
Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Cells(Farve_Cell.Row, "A") & "*", _
Sheets("Data").Range("D2:D50"), Sheets("Data").Range("F2:F50"), "F", 2)

If result = "Grøn" Then
Farve_Cell.Value = "GN"
   Else
   If result = "Gul" Then
   Farve_Cell.Value = "GL"
      Else
      If result = "Rød" Then
      Farve_Cell.Value = "RD"
         Else
         Farve_Cell.Value = ""
      End If
   End If
End If

Next Farve_Cell

End Sub
```